# jquery - fastest way to remove all rows from a very large table

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I thought this might be a fast way to remove the contents of a very large table (3000 rows):

```
$jq("tbody", myTable).remove();
```

But it's taking around five seconds to complete in firefox. Am I doing something dumb (aside from trying to load 3000 rows in to a browser)? Is there faster way to do it?

Answer (score 234, accepted):

```
$("#your-table-id").empty();
```

That's as fast as you get.

Comment: Hmmm. Frustrating. I would think that deleting would be much faster than insertion. Kind of makes me want to do really ugly stuff like just hide the table and create a new one when I want to update it.

Comment: Yeah, well... HTML was not created to show 3k rows in a page :) Can't you think of any paginated solution? That would make it much quicker. Sure it would demand more work, but it will be a much richer user experience.

Comment: I built it paginated originally, but the client insisted on scrolling :( Good news is 3k rows is an edge case. More common will be a few hundred.

Comment: @AlejandroSazo, that's right. I've just updated the example to make it clearer. Thanks.

Comment: This one is good. The problem is this will remove table headers as well.

Comment: Yes, this one removing headers too, not so much useful.

Comment: @asifaftab87 question is about removing "the contents of a very large table", that includes everything.

Comment: removes headers :(

Comment: This will remove everything in the table, including headers. I assume that @morgancodes wants to remove the contents, aka the rows, not the headers. For those who finds this later the solution would be `$('#mytable tbody').empty();`. This ensures that only the tbody gets emptied.

Answer (score 85):

It's better to avoid any kind of loops, just remove all elements directly like this:

```
$("#mytable > tbody").html("");
```

Comment: `html("")` calls `empty()` internally

Comment: Nice solution for me because it doesn't remove the header of a table. Thank you!

Comment: @Daria use selectors to the fullest, this will keep your headers in place: $('table tbody').empty();

Comment: what is the different between using ("#mytable > tbody") and ("#mytable  tbody").

Comment: If you have a nested table in a row of your table, it would remove those tbody tags as well. If you just have a single table, it shouldn't be much different.

Answer (score 21):

```
$("#myTable > tbody").empty();
```

It won't touch the headers.

Answer (score 10):

Using detach is magnitudes faster than any of the other answers here:

```
$('#mytable').find('tbody').detach();
```

Don't forget to put the tbody element back into the table since detach removed it:

```
$('#mytable').append($('<tbody>'));
```

Also note that when talking efficiency `$(target).find(child)` syntax is faster than `$(target > child)`. Why?  [Sizzle!](https://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/)

**Elapsed Time to Empty 3,161 Table Rows**

**Using the Detach() method**  (as shown in my example above):

- Firefox: 0.027s
- Chrome: 0.027s
- Edge: 1.73s
- IE11: 4.02s

**Using the empty() method:**

- Firefox: 0.055s
- Chrome: 0.052s
- Edge: 137.99s (might as well be frozen)
- IE11: Freezes and never returns

Comment: compared to `empty()`, `detach()` will keep all jQuery data associated with the removed elements.

Answer (score 3):

Two issues I can see here:

1. The empty() and remove() methods of jQuery actually do quite a bit of work. See John Resig's [JavaScript Function Call Profiling](http://ejohn.org/blog/function-call-profiling/) for why.
2. The other thing is that for large amounts of tabular data you might consider a datagrid library such as the excellent [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/) to load your data on the fly from the server, increasing the number of network calls, but decreasing the size of those calls. I had a very complicated table with 1500 rows that got quite slow, changing to the new AJAX based table made this same data seem rather fast.

Comment: Thanks artlung. Doing something a bit like that actually, getting all the data at once from the server, but only drawing table rows when needed.

Comment: Sounds like a good call. I am wondering if worrying about the number of rows in a table in a browser will always be an issue, or if as memory for most computers go up this will be less of an issue.

Comment: Memory isn't a problem with the amount of data I'm loading. The bottlneck is DOM manipulation.

Comment: I think we're saying the same thing. The more data you load, the more DOM nodes you load, to me these are related in terms of memory needed. I hope your situation has improved, regardless.

Answer (score 3):

this works for me :

> 1- add class for each row "removeRow"
>
> 2- in the jQuery

```
$(".removeRow").remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to remove only fast.. you can do like below..

```
$( "#tableId tbody tr" ).each( function(){
  this.parentNode.removeChild( this ); 
});
```

but, there can be some event-binded elements in table,

in that case,

above code is not prevent memory leak in IE... T-T and
not fast in FF...

sorry....

Answer (score -2):

You could try this...

```
var myTable= document.getElementById("myTable");
if(myTable== null)
    return;
var oTBody = myTable.getElementsByTagName("TBODY")[0];
if(oTBody== null)
    return;
try
{
    oTBody.innerHTML = "";
}
catch(e)
{
    for(var i=0, j=myTable.rows.length; i<j; i++)
        myTable.deleteRow(0);
}
```